# Xam.Plugin.Media Get Path

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using Xam.Media.Plugin to take pictures. The following is a snippet of my function:

```
public async Task<string> TakePhoto(string orderNr)
{
    ...
    var mediaOptions = new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
    {
        CompressionQuality = 25,
        PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Custom,
        CustomPhotoSize = 75,
        Directory = $"Order_{orderNr}"
    };
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions);
}
```

After the order is completed, I want to delete the entire folder with all of the pictures that were saved. How do I retrieve the path of the folder? I want to avoid getting the path after the picture is taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Android,

```
Environment.DirectoryPictures
```

on iOS

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
```

from [Github](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/search?q=environment&unscoped_q=environment)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

To get the private path `var privatePath = file.Path;`

To get the public Album path `var publicAlbumPath = file.AlbumPath;`

Reference: Documentation [sample project](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/samples/MediaSample/MediaSample/MediaPage.xaml.cs#L41)

Comment: I want to get it before the image is saved not afterwards. Please read my post carefully.